# How do I use a string as a keyword argument?

Tags: python

Specifically, I'm trying to use a string to arbitrairly filter the ORM.  I've tried exec and eval solutions, but I'm running into walls.  The code below doesn't work, but it's the best way I know how to explain where I'm trying to go

```
from gblocks.models import Image
f = 'image__endswith="jpg"' # Would be scripted in another area, but passed as text <user input>
d = Image.objects.filter(f)


#for the non-django pythonistas:
d = Image.objects.filter(image__endswith="jpg")
# would be the non-dynamic equivalent.
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
d = Image.objects.filter(**{'image__endswith': "jpg"})
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to split out the value from the keyword, then set up a dict using the keyword as the key, and the value as the value. You could then use the double-asterisk function paramater with the dict.

So...

```
keyword, sep, value = f.partition('=')
kwargs = {keyword: value.strip('"')}
d = Image.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

Note, this code assumes that there won't be any equals signs '=' in the keyword (they'll only be used to separate the keyword from the value), and the value will be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: Don't strip it. Use `ast.literal_eval()` instead.

Comment: Ok, related to that then, could I just use a regular eval() if I also wanted to catch `datetime.date(2005, 1, 3)` as a valid filter?

Answer (score 1):

The `eval` option should work fine, as long as you wrap it around the entire expression, not just the `f`:

```
f = 'image__endswith="jpg"'
d = eval('Image.objects.filter(' + f + ')')
```

Comment: It's dangerous to use `eval()` on user input. What if `f = "__import__('os').system('do something bad')"`? For more info, see [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by Ned Batchelder.