# Django: Query using contains each value in a list

Tags: django, django-models

I need to perform a django query that checks if a field contains all values within a list. The list will be of varying length

Example

```
User.objects.filter(first_name__contains=['x','y','z'])
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q

User.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, (Q(first_name__contains=x) for x in ['x', 'y', 'z'])))
```

for python 3

```
from functools import reduce
```

.

Comment: `User.objects.filter(reduce(...))` He is doing the equivalent of `User.objects.filter(Q(first_name__contains='x') & Q(first_name__contains='y') & Q(first_name__contains='z'))`

Comment: Very useful! You can also check to see if *any* of items in the list is contained in any of the objects by using operator.or_

Comment: what is operator? Do I need to import it?

Comment: @simi: You always need to import.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Your code is returning two results for the same db row if the row is assigned to two tags being searched! Please help.

Comment: @AdamSilver: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: Is it possible to order by most relevant depending on the number matching terms in each result?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams If you wanted to use this within a for loop, is there any way to replace `first_name` with a variable that changes on each iteration (`first_name`, `last_name` etc) *while keeping* the `__contains`? Right now the only way I can see to run this against multiple fields is repeating the entire function and hardcoding the different field names.

Comment: @py4on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932648/how-do-i-use-a-string-as-a-keyword-argument

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams lifesaver thanks - just seems weird appending `__contains` to a dictionary key string - never even tried it!

Comment: This is an incredible solution. It also fixed my issue where I needed to find all the rows that had one value in a given list by changing `contains.and_` to `contains.or_`

Comment: This line of code is very precious, but lack of any explanation makes this a terrible answer.

Comment: For anyone else who finds themselves in @ReimusKlinsman 's situation, wanting to check if the field contains "at least one of" the values you provide in a list -- you don't need all this code. The following will suffice: `YourModelClass.objects.filter(fieldName___in=your_list)`

Comment: How's the perf for large list?

Answer (score 39):

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q

q = ['x', 'y', 'z']
query = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(first_name__contains = item) for item in q))
result = User.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: Hey :). Welcome to SO. Mind adding a bit of meat to your answer? We normally like to provide a bit more info than a simple code-dump for an answer, just to help other users better understand what's happening :).  Thank you ^^

Comment: @Patrice Might as well make the same comment to the chosen answer, by the guy with 339K rep.  This answer has more context at least. :)

Comment: if using Python 3, use `import functools`  and use `functools.reduce`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10226421/1526703)

Answer (score 5):

More readable solution.

```
qs = User.objects.all()
for search_term in ('x', 'y', 'z'):
    qs = qs.filter(first_name__contains=search_term)
```

**Note: Querysets are lazy, so this code makes 1 DB query.**

Comment: Yeah, this works well for `AND` (`&`) queries. For `OR` (`|`) queries, `Q` objects must be used.

Comment: I ended up using this same approach. I think this solution is actually much more concise and much more readable than chaining multiple `Q`s in a line. And it suits op's problem well.

Comment: @Brandon yes but as @xyres said, for `OR` operator, you have to use `Q` objects

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db.models import Q
User.objects.filter(Q(first_name__contains=x)&Q(first_name__contains=y)&Q(first_name__contains=z))
```

Works for me on Django 1.8 python 2.7

doc => https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects

for more recent =>
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution didn't work for me, but this did:

```
list = ['x', 'y', 'z']
results = User.objects.filter(first_name__contains=list[0])
del list[0]

for l in list:
    results = results.filter(first_name__contains=l)
```

The first results variable will store a list of all the objects with the first_name name field value 'x'.

And then in the for loop you filter for 'y' amongst the first filter results. Now you have a QuerySet that should contain a list of items where both 'x' and 'y' can be found. Now amongst those you filter for any item that contains 'z' as well.

This should work for any length list.

Comment: This works fine. You can even lose del statement, by simply slicing the list, i.e., 
 `for l in list[1:]:`

Answer (score 1):

```py
the_list= []

data_list= ['x', 'y', 'z'] 

for i in data_list:

    a = User.objects.filter(first_name__contains=project).values('etc')

    the_list+= a
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in django 2.2, python 3.8, using lambda instead of 'operator'.
Explanations on lambda can be found here: https://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php

```
from functools import reduce
from django.db.models import Q

my_list = ['x','y','z']
User.objects.filter(reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [Q(first_name__contains= i for i in my_list]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't apply exactly here, but, if you have a `ManyToManyField` and you want to check if it contains a specific value, check this https://www.revsys.com/tidbits/tips-using-djangos-manytomanyfield/.

I have a "Products" and Django native "Users" model. My "Products" model has a many-to-many field `users` pointing to "Users". Then, I wanted to check if this list-like field contained the logged in user. I did that by `...users__username_icontains=request.user.username...` and the link above helped me to understand better what is a many-to-many field and how it works.