# NameError: global name 'reduce' is not defined

Tags: python, reduce

When I try this code in Python 3.x, I get an error message that says "NameError: global name 'reduce' is not defined".

```
def main():
    def add(x,y): return x+y
    reduce(add, range(1, 11))

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Why?

Comment: One of the reasons `reduce` was moved out of the built-ins was because it was frequently being used for addition, where `sum` is preferable (in this case, you could just do `sum(range(1, 11))`, or `sum(xrange(1, 11))` in Python 2).  Note also that there is an `add` function equivalent to yours in the standard library: `operator.add`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I'm going to guess that:

1. You are using Python 3, and
2. You are following a tutorial designed for Python 2.

The `reduce` function, since it is not commonly used, was removed from the built-in functions in Python 3. It is still available in the `functools` module, so you can do:

```
import functools

def main():
    def add(x,y): return x+y
    functools.reduce(add, range(1, 11))
```

Comment: "since it is not commonly used" is disputable.

Answer (score 10):

Also

```
# Import reduce from functools
from functools import reduce
```

Allows you to use `reduce` as though it were a built in function.

```
def main():
    def add(x,y): return x+y
    reduce(add, range(1, 11))
```