# Filtering on the concatenation of two model fields in django

Tags: django, django-queryset

With the following Django model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
  name = CharField(max_len=256)
  description = TextField()
```

I need to formulate a filter method that takes a list of n words (`word_list`) and returns the queryset of Items where each word in `word_list` can be found, either in the name or the description.

To do this with a single field is straightforward enough.  Using the reduce technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4824810/652693) (this could also be done with a `for` loop), this looks like:

```
q = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(description__contains=word) for word in word_list))
Item.objects.filter(q)
```

I want to do the same thing but take into account that each word can appear either in the name or the description. I basically want to query the concatenation of the two fields, for each word. Can this be done?

I have read that there is a concatenation operator in Postgresql, `||` but I am not sure if this can be utilized somehow in django to achieve this end.

As a last resort, I can create a third column that contains the combination of the two fields and maintain it via `post_save` signal handlers and/or `save` method overrides, but I'm wondering whether I can do this on the fly without maintaining this type of "search index" type of column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to use `Q` to do an `OR`:

```
lookups = [Q(name__contains=word) | Q(description__contains=word) 
           for word in words]
Item.objects.filter(*lookups)  # the same as and'ing them together
```

I can't speak to the performance of this solution as compared to your other two options (raw SQL concatenation or denormalization), but it's definitely simpler.