# Get all fields from DB where value contains number using Django

Tags: django

How to get all field from DB where value have number?

Example valid: `1test, tes1t, test1`

I suppose something like this: `field__contains`

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with a regex query.

```
Model.objects.filter(value__regex=r'\d')
```

Comment: That would match all numbers, not just from 1-9

Answer (score 0):

Use `icontains`:  [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains).

```
objs = Model.objects.filter(value__icontains="1")
```

The equivalent of doing an sql `ILIKE "%1%"` (case insensitive)

`contains` may work just as well actually if it's a number, that's a simple `LIKE`

Edit: To answer your comment yes you'd need to loop over the numbers. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824759/django-query-using-contains-each-value-in-a-list)

Comment: and for all number from 1 to 9 I need to write query?