# Does a containment filter exist in django's ORM?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Can I filter the query by this kind of criteria? Something like

```
Model.objects.filter(department__is_contained=x).values_list('department')
```

where

```
 x = 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD'
```

and my results should display stuff like

```
 ['AAA', 'AAA-BBB-CCC', 'BBB-CCC', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD', None]
```

Comment: Probably this http://stackoverflow.com/q/4824759/821594 can help

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on there and I can't get it working if I just try to copy it and adapt it to my problem. What's Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not. The SQL you're wanting to execute would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM model
WHERE 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD' like '%' + model.department + '%'
```

Django doesn't currently support the filter term on the left hand side. It may be possible to implement your own reverse_contains lookup with django 1.7 using [custom lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-lookups/).

```
class ReverseContains(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'rcontains'

    def as_sql(self, qn, connection):
        # untested! you'll have to validate this
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(qn, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(qn, connection)
        # note we're putting the rhs sql and params on the lhs
        params = rhs_params + lhs_params
        return "%s LIKE '%%' + %s + '%%' " % (rhs, lhs), params

from django.db.models.fields import CharField
CharField.register_lookup(ReverseContains)
```

And use it like so:

```
x = 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD'
Model.objects.filter(department__rcontains=x).values_list('department')
```

Or you could use [.extra(where=)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) to implement the search directly in SQL for that one query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-line solution:

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q

x = 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD'
User.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(department__contains=y) for y in x.split('-')))).values_list('department', flat=True)

# Result will be list of 'department' fields, that contains
# "AAA" or "BBB" or "CCC" or "DDD"
```

It could be hard to understand, so here is a more detailed variant of code:

```
total_filter_q = Q()
for y in x.split("-"):
    total_filter_q |= Q(department__contains=y)

# total_filter_q now represent this:
# Q(department__contains="AAA") | Q(department__contains="BBB") | Q(department__contains="CCC") | Q(department__contains="DDD")

User.objects.filter(total_filter_q).values_list('department', flat=True)
```

Result is the same as in one-line solution.

Here are some useful links:

- [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)
- [operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.or_)
- [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)
- [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. One question though - will this get AAA-BBB-ZZZ too although it is not contained in AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD? (I'm trying to avoid this)

Comment: Yes, it will. It will find all department, that contains 'AAA' or 'BBB' or 'CCC'. If it is not what you want, please define your conditions more precisely.

Comment: Sorry for that, I simply want to get all model objects whose department is contained in a string.

Comment: But your example in question: 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD' is not contained in ['AAA', 'AAA-BBB-CCC', 'BBB-CCC']...

Comment: ['AAA', 'AAA-BBB-CCC', 'BBB-CCC'] is a list of the model objects, and 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD' is the string. They are all contained in the string. Sorry if I don't really make sense :/