# Filter with arbitrary number or Q objects combined by OR logical operator

Tags: django, django-orm

**Django 1.10.1**

Search form. The user inserts words separated by spaces.
Necessary to find objects with **ANY** of these words in the title field.

I'm planning to use something like this:

```
Article.objects.filter(
    Q(title__icontains="table") | Q(title__icontains="helm")
)
```

I can make Q objects easily: q = Q(title__icontains="table").

But the obstacle is how to pass arguments to the filter method.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/

The syntax is **filter(**kwargs)**.

With a loop I can prepare a dictionary like this :

```
q_objects = {"1": Q(title__icontains="table"), "2": Q(title__icontains="glasses")}
```

But the problem is with that **"|"**. 
How to pass it to the filter method is a mystery to me. In other words I fail to build a filter with OR logical operator.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
queries = ['table, helm']
filter_ = 'title__icontains'

queryset.filter(reduce(lambda q1,q2: q1|q2, [Q(**{filter_: q}) for q in queries], Q()))

#This will build a QuerySet similar to this one:
queryset.filter(Q(title__icontains='table')|Q(title__icontains='helm'))
```

Comment: Dear Todor, thank you for your answer. Looks promising. I have to digest. If this works, I'll gladly accept.

Comment: Great answer! To me it looked more intuitive to reverse the order of the `Q` objects. Unfortunately that doesn't work, because the second parameter must support iteration.

Comment: Can you please tell me that if i am using this then what is the issue here:

Answer (score 3):

```
query = Q()
for word in words:
    query |= Q(title__icontains=word)
Article.objects.filter(query)
```

or

```
from operator import __or__ as OR
from functools import reduce

query = [Q(title__icontains=word) for word in words]
Article.objects.filter(reduce(OR, query))
```

Answer (score 1):

In the same line as proposed by @Todor and based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824759/django-query-using-contains-each-value-in-a-list), I like this syntax better:

```
reduce(operator.or_, (Q(title__icontains=x) for x in ['x', 'y', 'z']))
```

The full code with your example could be:

```
list_of_words = ['table', 'helm']   # words wanted by the user

Article.objects.filter(
     reduce(operator.or_, (Q(title__icontains=word) for word in list_of_words))
)
```