# Django: M2M field query using 'in' each value in a list

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I'm trying to find `Problem` objects having all the tags contained in `tags` related to it.

I have the following models.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Tag Name', max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(verbose_name='Description', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class Problem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Problem Name', max_length=250)
    contest_info = models.ManyToManyField(ContestInfo, verbose_name='Contest Info')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, verbose_name='Tags')
```

I've followed these posts: [Post-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39829064/filter-with-arbitrary-number-or-q-objects-combined-by-or-logical-operator) and [Post-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824759/django-query-using-contains-each-value-in-a-list). 
But, none worked.

My approaches.

**Approach 1**

```
query = [Q(tags__id__in=[tag]) for tag in tags]
problems = problems.filter(reduce(__and__, query))
```

Returns empty queryset.

**Approach 2**

```
for tag in tags:
    problems &= problems.filter(tags__id__in=[tag])
```

Returns result of OR instead of AND.
Using `intersection()` also gives the same result.

I want to get those problems which have all the tags in the list. How to do this ?

N.B: `problems` is a queryset and `tags` is list of ids of `Tag` objects.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270513/django-manytomany-filter-matching-on-all-items-in-a-list

Comment: postgresql is used?

Comment: @Basalex Yes. I used postgresql.

Comment: @itzMEonTV Thanks. That helped and solved the problem. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13275063/3968623) answer. Thanks to @itzMEonTV. 
But, it requires looping and I would like to achieve this without looping if possible.

Here's the solution.

```
for tag in tags:
    problems = problems.filter(tags__id=tag)
```

Answer (score 1):

For postgresql what you can is this (tested):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import JSONBAgg

problems = Problem.objects.annotate(tags_ids=JSONBAgg('tags__id'))
problems = problems.filter(tags_ids__contains=tags, tags_ids__contained_by=tags)
```

*where "tags is list of ids of Tag objects."

Comment: Ok. I'll try this asap. Btw, `tags` and `Tag` model both already contains `unique` ids and objects respectively. So, do i still need to filter them by `DISTINCT` ??

Comment: I think you don't have to use DISTINCT,but I wasn't sure, that`s why I added it to the answer

Comment: It's not working well. It's filtering out many objects. :(
I have other filters too applied on `problems`, not sure if that's the reason.

Comment: Are you sure that you used both 'contains' and 'contained_by' ? I`ve checked it for several times and it works just fine

Comment: Yes, I did. It's filtering out some objects that contain all the `tags`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169446/discussion-between-md-khairul-basar-and-basalex).