# Django QuerySet OR statement

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to obtain a QuerySet in Django so that the remaining objects satisfy at least one of a number of constrains (i.e. an OR statement)?

Something like:

```
remaining = Fruits.objects.all()

fruit_type = ['apple', 'orange'] # input from user
for fruit in fruit_type:
  remaining = remaining.filter(FruitType__icontains=fruit)
```

However, the above only returns FruitTypes that contain both 'orange' AND 'apple' (rather than orange OR apple).

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824759/django-query-using-contains-each-value-in-a-list

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects  go through this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Q object to perform complex queryset

```
from django.db.models import Q

for fruit in fruit_type:
    query |= Q(FruitType__icontains=fruit)

# Query the model
remaining = remaining.filter(query)
```

Refer to django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q for more information.

Comment: Is there a way to integrate this within a `for` loop? The user inputs fruit_type so it may be of length 0 up to 10. Worst case scenario I could write 10 `if` statements I suppose. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: yes you could. I edited the anser, hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
from django.db.models import Q
query = Q()
for fruit in fruit_type:
    query |= Q(FruitType__icontains=fruit)
remaining = remaining.filter(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fruit_type = ['apple', 'orange']
remaining = Fruits.objects.filter(FruitType__in=fruit_type)
```