# JSONField contains in Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

Hi im trying to know if a list contains another list, for this im using django + djongo, but i dont if i'm doing the query correctly

My model is

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    _id = models.ObjectIdField(primary_key = True)
    sku = models.JSONField(null= True)
    providers= models.JSONField(null= True)
    generic = models.JSONField(null= True)
    is_validated = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    tags = models.JSONField(null= True)
    objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

My serializer

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = (
            '__all__'
        )
```

generic is a list of strings like: `["martillo", "s2","s3","s4"]`

I want to get all items which the generic list contains the given list, i'm trying the next query but it returns all the items in database

`items = models.Item.objects.filter(generic__contains = ['martillo'])`

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you looking to see if generic equals a value in a list?

Comment: I edited my question, basically i'm trying to get all items which the field generic contains a given list

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q

Item.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, (Q(generic__contains=x) for x in ["martillo", "s2","s3","s4"] )))
```

Which is the equivalent of

```
Item.objects.filter(Q(generic__contains='martillo') & Q(generic__contains='s2') & Q(generic__contains='s3') etc...)
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/4824810/1730167