# How do I clear previous AJAX response data (NOT html/form data)? - Django/AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, django, ajax

I've built a Django app that submits an AJAX post request to my database.  The initial post request works fine, but every previous request is also returned after the first response.

Bottom line: Is there any way to clear the previous AJAX request/responses?

Here's the first response when I start my server and submit my first request (the request is for pk:1):

```
MedInput page loaded                                                       (index):46
Med Input Form Submitted                                                   (index):49
csrfmiddlewaretoken=i889gLsqdY9glqI59wRXLTOVehz9Lmp1i5IRikOsgvrGdBD9OpISolDrJ8pqJDmV&input_meds=lisinopril     (index):53
                                                                          (index):60  
[{…}]                                                                     (index):61
    0: {model: "medrec_app.medication", pk: 1, fields: {…}}
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

This is what happens when I submit another request (this request is for pk:3):

```
Med Input Form Submitted                                                   (index):49
csrfmiddlewaretoken=i889gLsqdY9glqI59wRXLTOVehz9Lmp1i5IRikOsgvrGdBD9OpISolDrJ8pqJDmV&input_meds=lisinopril     (index):53
                                                                           (index):60  
(2) [{…}, {…}]                                                             (index):61
    0: {model: "medrec_app.medication", pk: 1, fields: {…}}
    1: {model: "medrec_app.medication", pk: 3, fields: {…}}
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

And here's what happens when I request pk:1 and pk:3 at the same time:

```
Med Input Form Submitted                                                   (index):49
csrfmiddlewaretoken=i889gLsqdY9glqI59wRXLTOVehz9Lmp1i5IRikOsgvrGdBD9OpISolDrJ8pqJDmV&input_meds=lisinopril     (index):53
                                                                           (index):60  
    
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]                                                   (index):61 
    0: {model: "medrec_app.medication", pk: 1, fields: {…}}
    1: {model: "medrec_app.medication", pk: 3, fields: {…}}
    2: {model: "medrec_app.medication", pk: 3, fields: {…}}
    3: {model: "medrec_app.medication", pk: 1, fields: {…}}
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

I only want the responses from the most recent AJAX request/response (which as the last example shows, contains a variable number of models, not just the last one).

I've tried setting `$.ajax(..., cache: false, ...)` which didn't do anything, and I've tried emptying as many dictionaries/lists as I can find.

Is there any way to clear the previous request/responses?  What am I missing?

Here's my code:

**views.py**

```
class postMedRec(View):
    form_class = MedInputForm
    template_name = 'medrec_app/med_input.html'
    med_match = []
    med_set = Medication.objects.all()

    def post(self, request):
        if self.request.is_ajax and self.request.method == "POST":
            form = self.form_class(self.request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():

                input_meds = form.cleaned_data['input_meds']
                for med in self.med_set:
                    if re.search(med.generic_name,input_meds, re.IGNORECASE): 
                        self.med_match.append(med)
                ser_meds={}              
                ser_meds = serializers.serialize('json',self.med_match)
                return JsonResponse({'med_output':ser_meds}, status = 200)    
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"error", form.errors}, status= 200)
        return JsonResponse({"error":""}, status=400)
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name="medrec_app"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', MedInputView.as_view(), name="med_input"),
    path('post/ajax/med_rec/', postMedRec.as_view(), name="post_medrec"),
    path('meds/', MedicationList.as_view(), name="med_list"),
    path('meds/<int:pk>/', MedicationDetail.as_view(), name="med_detail"),
    path('meds/add/', AddMedView.as_view(), name="add_med"),
]
```

**med_input.html** (my template):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}



{% block header %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="display-2">Medication Reconciliation</h1>
</div>
{% endblock header %}

{% block content %}


<div class="container-fluid">
    <form id="med_input_form">
        <div class="form-group" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="{{form.input_meds.id_for_label}}">{{form.input_meds.label}}</label>
            {{form.input_meds}}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reconcile Meds</button> 
    </form>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul id="med_output">
    </ul>
</div>


<script>
    console.log('MedInput page loaded');
    
    $("#med_input_form").submit(function(event){
        console.log('Med Input Form Submitted');
        event.preventDefault();

        var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
        console.log(serializedData);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '{% url "medrec_app:post_medrec" %}',
            data: serializedData,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#med_output').html("");
                console.log($('#med_output').html());
                console.log(JSON.parse(response["med_output"]));
                var med_ajax = JSON.parse(response["med_output"]);
                $('#med_output').html('<li>'+med.fields.generic_name+'</li>');              
            }
        })
    });
</script>
{% endblock content %}

{% block javascript %}

{% endblock javascript %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set a list as a class variable, causing you to keep appending to it. also why are you using the re module to search?, leave that to the database there is `__iexact`, `__exact`, `__contains`, `__icontains`, `__regex`, `__iregex` and many more available in django when making queries.
This should work as intended:

```
class postMedRec(View):
    form_class = MedInputForm
    template_name = 'medrec_app/med_input.html'
    med_set = Medication.objects.all()

    def post(self, request):
        if self.request.is_ajax and self.request.method == "POST":
            form = self.form_class(self.request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():

                input_meds = form.cleaned_data['input_meds']
                med_match = list(self.med_set.filter(generic_name__iregex=input_meds))
                ser_meds={}              
                ser_meds = serializers.serialize('json',med_match)
                return JsonResponse({'med_output':ser_meds}, status = 200)    
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"error", form.errors}, status= 200)
        return JsonResponse({"error":""}, status=400)
```

Comment: The problem is now that if I write more than one potential match (e.g. `amlodipine lisinopril`), iregex doesn't return anything.  I know its a different issue, but I was trying to figure out that part, and I haven't been able to find a good answer so far.  If you have any advice, I would appreciate it, but otherwise thank you!

Comment: Do you actually need to use regex otherwise you could try using `icontains` and something as shown here [Django: Query using contains each value in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824759/django-query-using-contains-each-value-in-a-list) after splitting your input_meds on space

Comment: I _think_ I do need regex, for two reasons: 
1) I'm trying to do the reverse of `list(self.med_set.filter(...)`.  Instead of using `med_input` to look for a specific database entry, I'm trying to see if any database entry is found in `med_input` (that was the rationale for `for med in self.med_set`). 
2) My search terms need to be more complex; I need the database to look for multiple terms in med_input.  It seemed like regex was the easiest way to accomplish this.
I'm basically trying to get the database to look for a "best match" based on each line of `med_input`.

Comment: How about just post multiple values(regex) to the same key `input_meds` and then loop over them with `iregex` with the link given above. Your point 1 is invalid because the result is one and the same, you are checking whether an entry matches your regex and adding the entry to the list if it does.

Answer (score 0):

AANNNNDDD after my last response I realized what I had done wrong.  I think I needed my discussion with you to figure it out.

Originally I had declared  `med_match = []` outside the `POST` function, which was causing the issue.

I added `self.med_match = []` INSIDE the `POST` function, which cleared up the issue I was having.

So this works perfectly:

```
class postMedRec(View):
    form_class = MedInputForm
    template_name = 'medrec_app/med_input.html'
    med_match = []
    med_set = Medication.objects.all()

    def post(self, request):
        if self.request.is_ajax and self.request.method == "POST":
            form = self.form_class(self.request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                self.med_match = []
                input_meds = form.cleaned_data['input_meds']
                for med in self.med_set:
                    if re.search(med.generic_name,input_meds, re.IGNORECASE): 
                        self.med_match.append(med)
                ser_meds = serializers.serialize('json',self.med_match)
                return JsonResponse({'med_output':ser_meds}, status = 200)    
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"error", form.errors}, status= 200)
        return JsonResponse({"error":""}, status=400)
```

THANK YOU so much for working with me on this!!!