# Adding wordlist.txt file in exclude query

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I am trying to add `wordlist.txt` at the place of `exclude('wordlist.txt')`

**What i am trying to do :-**

I build a feature of exclude posts according to words, *For Example* :- If a post contains word "Bad" then exclude that post like :-

```
from django.db.models import Q

posts = Post.objects.exclude(Q(description__contains='bad') & Q(description__contains='bad1'))
```

BUT i am trying to exclude hundreds of words at the same time AND when i add all of them in this way then it will be very lengthy AND i don't want that, So i think I can make a file named **wordlist.txt** and put all my words that i want to exclude then `put the path of wordlist.txt in exclude query` so i do not have to write lengthy exlcude words in the query.

*For example :-*

```
posts = Post.objects.exclude(description__contains=wordlist.txt)
```

( Above example is just to explain, what i am trying to do )

**---------EDITED---------**

I tried by reading file first then putting in `exclude query` Like :-

views.py

```
import os
from django.conf import settings

file_ = open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'wordlist.txt'))

def posts_exclude(request):
    posts = Post.objects.exclude(description__contains=file_)

    context = {'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'mains/post_exclude.html', context)
```

wordlist.txt

```
good
```

BUT When i got to browser then unfortunately this is showing all the post without excluding.

I have no idea how can i do it .

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4824759/8388057)

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna, It also be very lengthy. Is there a way of putting `wordlist.txt` in query ?

Comment: Yes , read the txt, make a list pass it

Comment: Can i do it like this :-  **Post.objects.exclude(reduce(operator.and_, (Q(description__contains=x) for x in ['wordlist.txt'])))`** ?

Comment: no, you can't you need to read the file first `open('mytextfile.txt', r)` ... do some research

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna, edited my question , Have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the file `wordlist.txt` and then create a list with the words present in it.

```py
with open('wordlist.txt') as in_file:
    wordlist = in_file.read().splitlines()  // assuming that your file contains a word per line
```

Then in your query you can use `wordlist` as:

```py
posts = Post.objects.exclude(reduce(operator.and_, (Q(description__contains=x) for x in wordlist)))
```