# How passing string on filter keyword to Django Objects Model?

Tags: django, string, django-models, filter, keyword

How can i pass variables on a keyword  object filter on a view?

I have:

```
my_object = MyModel.objects.filter(my_keyword =my_filter_values)
```

I want to grab my_keyword from a variable coming from a string, like this:

```
my_string = 'my_keyword'
my_object = MyModel.objects.filter(my_string=my_filter_values)
```

But this doesn't work because Django doesn't know `my_string` from `MyModel`.

Edit: I've found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932648/how-do-i-use-a-string-as-a-keyword-argument/2932658#2932658) - I'll test and report back.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
my_filter = {}
my_filter[my_keyword] = my_filter_value

my_object = MyModel.objects.filter(**my_filter)
```

As an example, your variables might be:

```
my_keyword = 'price__gte'
my_filter_value = 10
```

Which would result in getting all objects with a `price >= 10`. And if you want to query on more than one field, you can just add another line below `my_filter[my_keyword]`:

```
my_filter[my_keyword] = my_filter_value
my_filter[my_other_keyword] = my_other_filter_value
```

Comment: last line should read :

`my_object = MyModel.objects.filter(**my_filter)`

Comment: Like in the case of keyword filter, how to use a variable in place of the **model**? For example, in the SO query, instead of `my_object = MyModel.objects.filter(my_keyword =my_filter_values)`, making use of a string like `var_model` and have `my_object = var_model.objects.filter(my_keyword =my_filter_values)`?

Comment: Hey, What if **my_keyword =my_filter_values** that whole thing stored in a string variable then how to use that in filter?