# Pass expression as named argument name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I´m using `dateutil.relativedelta()` which has named arguments corresponding to `time_unit` in my `age`-tuple and the code to get the relative time looks like:

```
def time_delta(age):
    now = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time()))
    if age.time_unit == "seconds":
        relative_time = now - relativedelta(seconds=int(age.value))
    elif age.time_unit == "minutes":
        relative_time = now - relativedelta(minutes=int(age.value))
    elif age.time_unit == "hours":
        relative_time = now - relativedelta(hours=int(age.value))
    elif age.time_unit == "days":
        relative_time = now - relativedelta(days=int(age.value))
    elif age.time_unit == "weeks":
        relative_time = now - relativedelta(weeks=int(age.value))
    elif age.time_unit == "months":
        relative_time = now - relativedelta(months=int(age.value))
    elif age.time_unit == "years":
        relative_time = now - relativedelta(years=int(age.value))
```

Is there any way in Python 2.7 to make this a one-liner instead using something along the lines of:

```
relative_time = now - relativedelta(eval("eval('age.time_unit') +'=' +age.value"))
```

Above doesn't work. Am I stuck with the `if/elif` or is there something nicer I could do here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932648/how-do-i-use-a-string-as-a-keyword-argument

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def time_delta(age):
    now = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time()))
    return now - relativedelta(**{age.time_unit: int(age.value)})
```

(the code wasn't tested, but should probably work)

Answer (score 0):

```
def time_delta(age):
    now = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time()))
    if age.time_unit in ["seconds","minutes","hours","days","weeks","months","years"]:
        exec("relative_time = now - relativedelta({}=int(age.value))".format(age.time_unit))
```

I know, I know. `exec`!!! It's safe in this mode, guys.

Edit: Typo. `exec`, not `eval`