# String as a keyword argument and combine multiple dict from str.partition() output to one single dict

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a string as below:

```
src = "raidlevel=1,slot=0,DISK=1i:1:1_1i:1:2"
```

and I followed the code example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932648/how-do-i-use-a-string-as-a-keyword-argument)  to convert it to a dictionary based on a separator (=).

```
for i in src.split(','):
    key, sep, val = i.partition('=')
    dictRaid = {key.lower():val}
    if all(k in dictRaid for k in ('raidlevel', 'slot', 'disk')):
       print "all arguments present"
       print dictRaid
```

The issue what I am facing now is, the **partition**() function returns multiple individual dictionaries and due to that the **if all**() condition returns False rather True.
How to combine these multiple individual dictionary results from **partition**() function to one single dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dictRaid = {}
src = "raidlevel=1,slot=0,DISK=1i:1:1_1i:1:2"
for i in src.split(','):
    key, sep, val = i.partition('=')
    dictRaid[key.lower()] = val
if all(k in dictRaid for k in ('raidlevel', 'slot', 'disk')):
    print "all arguments present"
    print dictRaid
```

**Output:**

```
all arguments present
{'slot': '0', 'raidlevel': '1', 'disk': '1i:1:1_1i:1:2'}
```

- Declare your dict `dictRaid` outside the for-loop and the use `dict.update` to add key-value
- `if all(k..` should be outside of the for-loop.

Comment: Why `update()` instead of just `dictRaid[key.lower()] = val`?

Answer (score 2):

```
src = "raidlevel=1,slot=0,DISK=1i:1:1_1i:1:2"
dict(w.lower().split('=') for w in src.split(','))
# {'raidlevel': '1', 'slot': '0', 'disk': '1i:1:1_1i:1:2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict` constructor with a list of 2-item lists:

```
src = "raidlevel=1,slot=0,DISK=1i:1:1_1i:1:2"

dictRaid = dict(i.split('=') for i in src.lower().split(','))

print(dictRaid)

{'raidlevel': '1', 'slot': '0', 'disk': '1i:1:1_1i:1:2'}
```

Note also that your `if` condition can be written more clearly as a `set` difference rather than `if all(...)`.

```
check_keys = {'raidlevel', 'slot', 'disk'}

if check_keys.issubset(dictRaid):
    # do something
```