# how to use a string variable to define dataarray name when adding to xarray dataset?

Tags: python, python-xarray, keyword-argument

I want to add a `dataarray` to an `xarray` `dataset`, and do so by using `xarray.assign`, but I don't know how to define the name of the dataarray using a string variable (i.e. to call the new entry "myvar":

```
import xarray as xr

varname="myvar"
vals=[1,2,3]
coords=[4,5,6]
ds=xr.Dataset(data_vars={},coords={'xcoord':coords})
ds=ds.assign(varname=(['xcoord'],vals))
ds.to_netcdf("test.nc")

ds.close()
```

This gives me the variable called "varname" - how do I use a variable here?

Comment: Actually, both should be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932648/how-do-i-use-a-string-as-a-keyword-argument

Comment: oops, thanks, I was too focused on "assign" for my search before posting, thanks and apologies for the dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a dictionary where `varname` is the key:

```
kwargs = {varname: (['xcoord'],vals)}
```

And then pass that dictionary as the argument to `ds.assign()`, using `**` syntax:

```
ds=ds.assign(**kwargs)
```

If you like, you can do it all in one step, without creating an intermediate dictionary:

```
ds=ds.assign(**{varname: (['xcoord'],vals)})
```